# What is the correct event to use to catch a new row when the user has finished editing?

Tags: vb.net, bindingsource

I need to add several bits of data to my record such as created date and createdby when a user adds a new row in a datatable.
I am looking for the correct event on the bindingsource to catch this so i can add the information then save the record before the user moves onto the next row.
C# seems to have a RowEditEnding event on the datagrid but a)i'm not using C# and b) I can see from searching that its better to work on the datasource, which in this case is a bound datagrid so i presume i should be looking at the bindingsource object but there is not an obvious event to choose.

I think need something like currentchanged with condition if isdirty then...

Please can someone point me in the right direction here.

thanks

john

Comment: What platform? `RowEditEnding` is WPF's DataGrid event. Btw, there's no `C# DataGrid`. A DataGrid (or DataGridView?) is a .Net object. Its events/properties/methods are available to all .Net languages.

Comment: Thanks Jimi for coming back so quickly

Comment: Its Win10 but i think i've solved it

Comment: I think I've solved it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this seems to work

```
    Private Sub TblOppQuoteDetailBindingSource_CurrentChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles TblOppQuoteDetailBindingSource.CurrentChanged

    If sender.current IsNot Nothing Then
        If sender.current.IsNew Then
            Dim nr As DataRowView = sender.current
            nr.Item("OppQuoteID") = 2
            nr.Item("Created") = Now
            nr.Item("CreatedBy") = G_UserName

        ElseIf sender.current.isedit Then
            Dim nr As DataRowView = sender.current
            nr.Item("OppQuoteID") = 2
            nr.Item("Updated") = Now
            nr.Item("UpdatedBy") = G_UserName

        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

is this the correct way?